# Database normalization, many to one

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I try to normalize my database. Table_3 rows are childs from Table_1 or Table_2:
[image: Wrong]

**This is my correction:**

[image: Right?]

Am i right?

Comment: not enough information to help you.  the top design looks like a valid design linking table 1 to table 2.  the bottom design looks very odd.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Table3 are children of Table1 or Table2. So either Table1_id or Table2_id is null. And i believe its bad.